# R-language, convert data.frame to time series

Tags: r, dataframe

i've a data.frame with structure:

```
> str(MSK)
'data.frame':   14685 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ code  : Factor w/ 423 levels "100 975","101 479",..: 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 281 ...
 $ period: Date, format: "2010-01-01" "2010-02-01" "2010-03-01" "2010-04-01" ...
 $ sales : num  515 195 414 410 551 18 373 74 62 313 ...
```

I need to convert this data to a matrix or another data.frame with rows: "period" and columns: "code".
Fore some "code" time series are'n full. And missing value must be equal NA.

For example, i've a data like this:

```
code data sales
303  1day 200
303  2day 300
303  3day 400
404  2day 250
404  3day 350
606  2day 167
```

I need to get:

```
     303 404 606
1day 200  NA  NA
2day 300 250 167
3day 400 350  NA
```

It's not so hard to do it directly, but i want to know a right way to convert.

Sorry for my language, My native language is Russian and I'm a poor student at school.

Thank you for your attention. =)

Comment: You could do much worse than spending the next 30 minutes reading the _ample_ documentation in the (excellent and widely used) [**zoo**](http://cran.rstudio.com/package=zoo) package... which answered this and other questions, and does it well.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel, i'm added explanation. Zoo can do so? If don't, then what can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `dcast` from `reshape2`.
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reshape2/reshape2.pdf

```
 my_df <- data.frame(
                        period=c("1day","2day","3day","2day"),
                        code=c(303,303,304,305),
                        sale=c(100,200,300,400))
 library(reshape2)
 my_df2 <- dcast(my_df,period~code,value.var="sale")
```

Output:

```
   > my_df
      period code sale
    1   1day  303  100
    2   2day  303  200
    3   3day  304  300
    4   2day  305  400

    > my_df2
      period 303 304 305
    1   1day 100  NA  NA
    2   2day 200  NA 400
    3   3day  NA 300  NA
```

Comment: I'm add an explain. Your code doesn't work as i espect, but thanks for the reshape2 and melt, i'm trying to read manual.